# recursive generator when meet string

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, generator

Here is my code :

```
def flatten(nested):
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested
```

It's the example in a book which called Beginning Python From Novice to Professional written by Magus Lie Hetland.

It says ,if there is a string in this list it will be  endless by recursion .
Yes, It's true.But what should I do, if I use this generator? I'm a new learner.Thank you for your teaching. At last, my English is so poor, I'm so sorry,if you read hard. I'll try my best to improve.

Comment: I'ts my first time to come StackOverflow. Please help me.Also, I find a good thing.I should use four space instead of ``` ```.My code in this page looks so bad. QAQ. I always uses ```in markdown.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite recursion occurs in the case of a string because it is **iterable**.

Your function relies on a TypeError to break out of recursion, so here is how the code would normally proceed:

```
> flatten([[1,2],[3,4]])     ---function call
> for e in ([[1,2],[3,4]])   ---outer loop
> for i in flatten([1,2])    ---inner loop
> for e in ([1,2])           ---recursion outer loop
> for i in flatten(1)        ---recursion inner loop
> for e in 1 [TYPE_ERROR]    ---recursion2 outer loop
> yield 1                    ---recursion2 except call
> etc...
```

As you can see, when the program attempts to iterate over an integer (`1`), a TypeError occurs breaking the function out of recursion. This, however, will not happen with a string:

```
> flatten([["hi","hello"],[3,4]])     ---function call
> for e in ([["hi","hello"],[3,4]])   ---outer loop
> for i in flatten(["hi","hello"])    ---inner loop
> for e in (["hi","hello"])           ---recursion outer loop
> for i in flatten("hi")              ---recursion inner loop
> for e in "hi"                       ---recursion2 outer loop
> for i in flatten("h")               ---recursion2 inner loop
> for e in "h"                        ---recursion3 outer loop
> for i in flatten("h")               ---recursion3 inner loop
> and so on forever
```

Because python will still iterate over single character strings, and the function relies on a type exception to stop recursion, the function will run indefinitely (well, until you reach the maximum recursion depth and your program crashes at least).

As such, if you want to use this function with strings, you simply need to make a condition to check if the function is iterating over a string:

```
def flatten(nested):
    try:
        if isinstance(nested, str):
                yield nested
        else:        
            for sublist in nested:
                for element in flatten(sublist):
                    yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested
```

With the added if statement you should be able to use strings:

```
mylist = [["hi","hello"],[3,4]]

for e in flatten(mylist):
    print(e)

---Output---

hi
hello
3
4
```

Comment: OK,Thank you~I know this question.But If I want to receive single letter by your way, what should I do.For example, ['hello',[3,4]]---->['h','e','l','l','o',3,4]

Comment: 3Q,I have find the way

Answer (score 0):

I think @avghdev makes a big mistake by checking for `str` instead of checking for `list` – `list` is the positive scenario in which case we want to recur. In all other cases, we want to yield the ordinary value

Below, we use `yield from` to delegate to another generator. In this case, our `flatten` generator is recursive because it yields to itself.

As a result of this implementation, pain and suffering are removed from the program.

```
def flatten (xs):
  for x in xs:
    if isinstance (x, list):
      yield from flatten (x)
    else:
      yield x

for x in flatten ([ 1, [ '2', [ 3, [ '4', [ 5, None ]]]]]):
  print (x)

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# None
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,I have find my solution:

```
 def flatten(nested):
    try:
        if isinstance(nested, str):
            for i in nested:
                yield i
        else:
            for sublist in nested:
                for element in flatten(sublist):
                    yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested


lista = [[1, 2], 3, ['abc',[1, 'abc']]]
for i in flatten(lista):
    print(i)
----Output----
1
2
3
a
b
c
1
a
b
c
```